# How to print specific column in row wise using unix?

Tags: unix, awk, grep, nawk

I have one input file which is given below.

```
Values,series,setupresultcode,nameofresultcode,resultcode
2,9184200,,serviceSetupResultempty,2001
11,9184200,0,successfulReleasedByService,2001
194,9184200,1,successfulDisconnectedByCallingParty,2001
101,9184200,2,successfulDisconnectByCalledParty,2001
2,9184201,0,successfulReleasedByService,2001
78,9184201,1,successfulDisconnectedByCallingParty,2001
32,9184201,2,successfulDisconnectByCalledParty,2001
4,9184202,0,successfulReleasedByService,2001
63,9184202,1,successfulDisconnectedByCallingParty,2001
37,9184202,2,successfulDisconnectByCalledParty,2001
```

I want output as given below:

```
Series,successfulReleasedByService,successfulDisconnectedByCallingParty,successfulDisconnectByCalledParty,serviceSetupResultempty
9184200,11,194,101,2
9184202,4,63,37,
```

Keep series as common print value of series.i.e. first column with respect to result code.i.e third(integer) or fourth(string) column in input file.

For example: the second column of the data has n number of series; take 9184200. That series having 4 setupresultcode (empty,0,1,2). Name of each result code is given in 4th column. I want to print if resultcode is 0;  i.e. successfulReleasedByService then print value 11 with respect to series 9184200.

Comment: sorry, I do not understand the logic of the transformation. Could you expand and explain more in depth?

Comment: I think @gyrous wants to turn `unique(setupresultcode)` values into column headers, `unique(series)` into rows, and list in each row-column pair the corresponding `Vales`.

Comment: sorry, even i am confused. :(. let me try to explain for example: second column having n number of series take 9184200. that series having 4 setupresultcode (empty,0,1,2). name of each result code is given in 4th column. i want to print if resultcode is 0.i.esuccessfulReleasedByService then print value 11 with respect to series 9184200.

Comment: (1) Why no `9184201` line? (2) where do `10,200` come from?

Comment: Please edit the explanation into the question, rather than adding comments.

Comment: Does the transformation have to deal with possibly missing codes?  Are the codes presented in order in the data?  Are the codes for a series always contiguous?

Comment: The transformation does not deal with missing code. i am just trying to print the output as i bementioned before to make it simple. so i can get series with respect to result codes. simply i can say i am arranging in order which i want

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work although I haven't tested it, regard it as some kind of pseudo code.

```
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN
{
  number_of_series=0;
}
{
  #This part will be executed for every line
  if ($3 =="0" || $3 == "1" || $3 == "2")
  {
    for (i=1; i<=number_of_series; i++)
    {
      #If the series has already been added
      if(seriesarray[i] == $2)
      {
        #Concat the results
        seriesarray[$2]=seriesarray[$2]","$1;
      }
      #If it's a new series
      else
      {
        number_of_series++;
        seriesarray[$2]=$1;
      }
    }
  }
}
END
{
  #Iterate over the series and print the series id and the concatenated results
  for (series in seriesarray)
  {
    print series, seriesarray[series];
  }
}
```

This would yield something like

> 9184200,11,194,101
>
> 9184201,2,78,32
>
> 9184202,4,63,37

Comment: Hi kristofer, thanks for your post. can u tell me onething how to give input? I am getting error like this.

Comment: ./test.sh < test1
/bin/nawk: syntax error at source line 3
 context is
        BEGIN  >>> 
 <<< 
/bin/nawk: bailing out at source line 3